# Var vs. Let Keyword With Global Object

Tags: javascript, object, global, var, let

When we use the var keyword outside of a function, it creates a global variable and attaches that global variable to window object in the browser. In contrast, when we use a let keyword to declare a global variable, that global variable is not attached to the window object. Then, where does the global variable declared by let keyword go?

Comment: let is not globally scoped as far as my understanding goes. You can find more detail here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var

Comment: Kindly refer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNC6slYCj50&list=PLlasXeu85E9cQ32gLCvAvr9vNaUccPVNP&index=9 for better clarity, even you can refer the whole tutorial for core javascript concept, you will thank me later

Comment: Chapter 2 in [@T.J.Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) 's [JavaScript, The New Toys](https://amzn.to/3csycQL) is also explaining this in great detail